# Delphi XE3. TStyleManager.SetStyle works for all forms in application. How set style only on 1 form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, vcl-styles

I need a form for testing Styles.
And go apllying each style only in that form. But the TStyleManager.SetStyle applies to all forms in application. How can I do for apply style only in current form?

```
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var styleName: String;
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.Clear;
      for styleName in TStyleManager.StyleNames do
        ListBox1.Items.Add(styleName);
    end;
.......
    procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin // this applies to all forms in application, I want apply only this form!
      TStyleManager.SetStyle(ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
    end;
```

Comment: [`How to disable VCL styles in Delphi`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8598961/576719).

Answer (score 4):

The VCL Styles are application wide, and are not designed to only be applied to a particular form. But you can disable the styles in the forms and the controls removing the  elements from the [`StyleElements`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Tutorial:_Using_TControl.StyleElements_in_VCL_Applications) property.

Now according to your question "`I need a form for testing Styles...`" maybe you are looking a **preview** form for the VCL Styles and if that is the case you can try this article [`Exploring Delphi XE2 – VCL Styles Part III`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/exploring-delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-part-iii/) which explains how create a preview for the VCL Styles. Also the [VCL Styles Utils](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/) project includes a component called [`TVCLStylesPreview`](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.Ext.pas)  and [sample application](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Vcl%20Styles%20Preview) of how use it.

Check this sample image of the component

[image]